# Repeating characters X times in cmd

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Lets say I have a variable `%mynumber%`

I want the variable `%mycharacter%` to have the value of a specific single letter or character repeated by `%mynumber%`

So if the the value of `%mynumber%` is `15` and if i `echo %mycharacter%` i want it to return e.g. `sssssssssssssss`

If the the value of `%mynumber%` is `10` and if i `echo %mycharacter%` i want it to return e.g. `ssssssssss`

If the the value of `%mynumber%` is `7` and if i `echo %mycharacter%` i want it to return e.g. `sssssss`

Also, instead of "s" i want spaces " "

Answer (score 4):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET mychar=e
SET mynumber=12
FOR /l %%i IN (2,1,%mynumber%) DO CALL set "mychar=%%mychar%%%mychar%"
ECHO +%mychar%+
SET mychar=a
SET mynumber=1
FOR /l %%i IN (2,1,%mynumber%) DO CALL set "mychar=%%mychar%%%mychar%"
ECHO +%mychar%+
SET mychar=s
SET mynumber=2
FOR /l %%i IN (2,1,%mynumber%) DO CALL set "mychar=%%mychar%%%mychar%"
ECHO +%mychar%+
SET mychar=y
SET mynumber=7
FOR /l %%i IN (2,1,%mynumber%) DO CALL set "mychar=%%mychar%%%mychar%"
ECHO +%mychar%+
SET "mychar= "
SET mynumber=6
FOR /l %%i IN (2,1,%mynumber%) DO CALL set "mychar=%%mychar%%%mychar%"
ECHO +%mychar%+
GOTO :EOF
```

Note the method of assigning a single space. Quoting the `set` parameters makes sure that any extra (invisible) terminal spaces on the line are NOT included in the assignment and that the editor you use won't helpfully eliminate terminal spaces that you actually want.